# Is quantum field theory impredicative?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

We define a field as a physical quantity assigned to each point in spacetime. In turn, spacetime is often defined or understood as "all there is," where there are fields.

So logically I wonder whether or not this is an impredicative theory, i.e. self-referential/circular?

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted; the OP's wording of his understanding of QFT is odd, but the question itself - whether the definition of a QFT is self-referential, is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No, it is not an impredicative theory.

Longer answer: Either if you take the Wightman axioms, or the Algebraic approach, the theories of quantum fields are perfectly defined theories within ZFC. Essentially, you can see a quantum field theory as a noncommutative probability theory (that is actually true for any quantum theory). Such theory is described by an algebra of observables (random variables) that should at least contain the Weyl C* algebra of canonical commutation relations. The Weyl C* algebra is characterized by an underlying infinite dimensional real symplectic vector space that specifies the nature of the quantum field(s) considered. In suitable representations (e.g. the Fock representation for free theories) it is possible to define the self-adjoint generators of the Weyl operators, that are the so-called quantum fields. There is one quantum field for each vector of the real symplectic vector space. Therefore it is often convenient to see the quantum fields as maps from the symplectic vector space to the self-adjoint operators. These maps are called operator-valued distributions. However, as usual distributions, they cannot be evaluated at single points of the spacetime, but they make sense only as "global" objects acting on "test functions" (i.e. vectors in the symplectic space).

Comment: Thanks. But can you use some math notation in QFT to show that  "the quantum fields are maps from the symplectic vector space to the self-adjoint operators."

Comment: @VictorVMotti What do you mean by "can you use some math notation"? Of course I can, but to define everything from scratch here would be rather long. What is your level of knowledge? Do you know e.g. how the Weyl C* algebra of canonical commutation relations is defined for bosonic systems?

Comment: My level is limited to this note by Tong on QFT. I get field CCR and how filed operator works on a quantum state but don't get Weyl C* and maps from the symplectic vector...http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/qft.pdf

Comment: @VictorVMotti The mathematical definition of quantum fields needs C* algebras and symplectic spaces and some advanced mathematical machinery. You can look up Segal's works on qft (or the book baez-segal-zhou), or more recent works like the book of derezinsky-gérard. However a graduate-level knowledge of mathematics is probably needed. Anyways, the point is that there is a mathematically rigorous framework for qft that has no problems of impredicativity or vicious-circle-like paradoxes.